# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK not working as expected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a stack with 3 Activities: `A, B, C`. From `Activity C` I start the `Activity B` setting on the Intent the flag: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. According to the documentation this should bring the `Activity B` with the underlying task on the front resulting in a stack : `A, B, C, A, B`. 
However the actual stack is `A, B, C, B`. When I press the Back-Button from the `Activity B` I go through the above stack in the reverse order: `B -> C -> B -> A`.
The code which starts the the `Activity B` from `Activity C` is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

According to the docs the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` causes the same behavour as the `"singleTask"` launchMode value. If I set in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file the launchmode `"singletask"` on the `Activity B`, then it produces the expected behavour as described in the docs: the task `A, B` comes to the front resulting in a stack `A, B, C, A, B`. 
Why does not it work with the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`? Is some `affinity` configuaration also necessary in this case?

Comment: Based on what you have written, there is no way that you would get a stack containing "A->B->C->A->B" which contains 2 instances of "A", since you have not started 2 instances of "A". Also, I don't understand where you get the idea that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `launchMode="singleTask"` are similar. `taskAffinity` settings are necessary in order to actually produce multiple tasks for your application. But it sounds like you don't want multiple tasks. Your description is confusing. Please post your entire manifest.

Comment: I get the stack "A->B->C->A->B" when I declare the Activity B as "singleTask" in AndroidManifest.xml file. I want and I expect however to get the same stack using the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK without defining anything in the AndroidManifest.xml file. According to the docs It produces the same behavour as "singleTask". It is stated explicitly in the docs https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe you. There is something else going on. Just declaring `B` with `launchMode="singleTask"` without specifying `taskAffinity` will not generate the stack "A->B->C->A->B". Please post your manifest. Also, the current documentation does state that the flag produces the same behaviour, but that is wrong. It depends on too many things that are not stated :-(

Comment: You can see what the task stack actually looks like by using `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`